# Cannot call modal.show() after remove(). Please create a new modal instance

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using the suggested technique in the tutorial to create a [modal](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/) in my controller that works as long as I do not navigate away from the view using that controller. In addition to this, I have created a service to set up communication between controllers. If I navigate away from the view and return to it (re-triggering the controller), then the modal no longer works. The console error I get is:

`Cannot call modal.show() after remove(). Please create a new modal instance`

This is my code so far:

```
// services.js

function ModalPopupCommunicationService() {
  var serviceFunction;
  return {
    set: function(funcFromCtrl) {
      serviceFunction = funcFromCtrl;
    },
    call: function() {
      serviceFunction();
    }
  }
}

// controller.js

function PopupController($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $state, ModalPopupCommunicationService) {
  $scope.showPaymentOptionsPopup = function() {
    $ionicPopup.confirm({
      title: 'Payment Options',
      cssClass: 'popup-vertical-buttons',
      buttons: [{
        text: "Add",
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function() {
          ModalPopupCommunicationService.call();
        }
      }, {
        text: "Edit",
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function() {
          $state.go('sidemenu.payment-edit-card', {
            "profile": 1
          });
        }
      }, {
        text: "Close",
        type: 'button-dark',
        onTap: function() {}
      }]
    });
  };
}

function ModalController($scope, $ionicModal, $stateParams, ModalPopupCommunicationService) {
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('views/payment-add-card.view.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.addCardModal = modal;
  })

  $scope.openAddCardModal = function() {
    $scope.addCardModal.show()
  }

  ModalPopupCommunicationService.set($scope.openAddCardModal);

  $scope.closeAddCardModal = function() {
    $scope.addCardModal.hide();
  };

  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.addCardModal.remove();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are calling `$scope.addCardModal.remove();` when the scope of the controller is destroyed. Comment that line and it should work. Its not recommended to keep the modal in memory to avoid memory leaks. You can create it when you return back to the view again by calling `$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl` again.

Comment: Did this: http://pastebin.com/APEZAMEi and still getting an error message. Can you show me a code sample of what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you pass the reference to the function attached to the controller $scope into a service to share it with another controller. The problem is that a scope can not be cleaned up by the GC if it is still accessible by another JS object. I think this causes the error that you are getting when you re-enter the controller.

I'm wondering why you need to pass the reference to the function into another controller. I think that you need to re-factor your code.